# UITableview only allow swipe to delete in one direction

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview, uikit

I have a tableview in which Edit mode is enabled, so the user can swipe in any direction on a cell to bring up the delete button. However, I have a gesture on the whole tableview for right swipes to do something else, unrelated to the deletion. I would like it if the swipe to delete only worked on a left swipe, so that my gesture recognizer would be called on the right swipe. Right now, the tableview swipe completely overrides my gesture recognizer.

Is there any way to fix this?

Thanks,

Comment: Some could say that since the system-provided gesture works in both directions, there are some users who are used to one direction, and some others who are used to the other. It can be said that your question is asking for a way to mess with the expectations of at least one of those groups of people. What about adding a modify button that shows the regular delete (-) buttons on the left of each row? The swipe gesture is, anyway, a shortcut, and I would not rely on it, alone, to fulfill a deletion use case.

Answer (score 4):

You just need to add a SwipeGesture to tableView and important thing is do not set the delegate of swipeGesture and do not implement gestureRecognizer `shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer` function.

```
UISwipeGestureRecognizer *swipeRight = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc]initWithTarget:self action:@selector(callYourMehod:)];
swipeRight.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionRight;
[self.table addGestureRecognizer:swipeRight];
```

It should work as I have implemented and used it in my code
This is how table cells will not go in edit mode on right swipe.