# How to disable swipe in particular direction on UITableViewCell in iOS?

Tags: ios, uitableview, direction, uiswipegesturerecognizer

I have implemented swipe-to-delete option in my table view by adding the following two methods:

```
- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canEditRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    return YES;
}



- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete)
    {
        //Action to delete
    }
}
```

This working well, and whenever I swipe on the cells (both left-to-right and right-to-left), a red color delete button appears well.

But I want to show the delete button only if, the user swipes from right-to-left direction. When the user swipes in left-to-right, I want to perform someother actions. Is it possible to findout the direction here?

Comment: possible duplicate of [UITableview only allow swipe to delete in one direction](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13790033/uitableview-only-allow-swipe-to-delete-in-one-direction)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add a swipe gesture recognizer to the table view for the direction you want to ignore.

```
UISwipeGestureRecognizer *swipe = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc]initWithTarget:self action:@selector(emptyMethod:)];
swipe.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionLeft;
[self.tableView addGestureRecognizer:swipe];
```

Then implement the emptyMethod.. this method won't do anything.

```
- (void)emptyMethod {}
```

Everytime you swipe left, the empty method will be called and does.. nothing.

Comment: Thank you for your reply and it works fine for me. Only thing is, for my requirement, the swipe direction is right side. So I changed UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionLeft into UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionRight in the above code and its works pretty well. I have some more doubts regarding this..

- Can I change the size & color of this default "Delete" button?
- How can I find whether the "Delete" button is visible or not?

Comment: I doubt that you can change the button, but I don't know.. to find out whether the button is visible or not you can check if your UITableView is in editing mode. BOOL visible = self.tableView.editing;

Comment: what is the implementation of this on swift 5? I mean, how to Ignore the swipe right to left?